# How to access text inside this <div class> that has no id? Using BeauitfulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below in the grayed out area is some text that I am trying to extract in a page.

I dont know how to access the text in the gray area. I tried the following but it did not work. The class does not have an id - how to get the text inside it?

```
comment = soup.find("div", {"class",  "GCARQJCDEXD"})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the element by *matching a `class` attribute to an empty string*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="GCARQJCDEXD">
    <div class="clearfix hidden">something here</div>
    <div class>
        desired text
    </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

comment = soup.find("div", {"class": "GCARQJCDEXD"}).find("div", {"class": ""})
print(comment.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints `desired text`.